# Django : Cannot assign "'3'": "LineaPedido.producto_id" must be a "Producto" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Estoy tratando de guardar una lista de compra en Django pero en cuando hago click en el botón de mi página me salta el siguiente error:

> Cannot assign "'3'": "LineaPedido.producto_id" must be a "Producto" instance.

Eh visto pregustas similares pero no me sirven.

**models.py**

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

    @property
    def total(self): 
       return self.lineapedido_set.aggregate(
           total=Sum(F('precio')*F('cantidad'), output_field=FloatField())
       )['total']

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'pedidos'
        verbose_name = 'pedido'
        verbose_name_plural = 'pedidos'
        ordering=['id']

class LineaPedido(models.Model):        
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    producto_id = models.ForeignKey(Producto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pedido_id = models.ForeignKey(Pedido, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.cantidad} unidades de {self.producto_id.nombre}'

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'lineapedidos'
        verbose_name = 'Línea Pedido'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Línea Pedidos'
        ordering=['id']
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/autenticacion/logear")
def procesar_pedido(request):
    pedido=Pedido.objects.create(user=request.user)
    carro=Carro(request)
    lineas_pedido=list()

for key, value in carro.carro.items():
    lineas_pedido.append(LineaPedido(
        producto_id=key,
        cantidad=value["cantidad"],
        user=request.user,
        pedido_id=pedido
    ))

LineaPedido.objects.bulk_create(lineas_pedido)

messages.succes(request, 'El pedido se ha creado correctamente')

return redirect('../tienda')
```

**Nuevo error a partir de la repuesta de @Kevin Ramirez Zavalza**
[image: captura de pantalla a django]

**Y gracias de antemano a los que me respondan**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en tu view, estas generando una lista de objetos para luego hacer el bulk_create, el problema es que el campo producto_id esta esperando un objeto de tipo producto, no un pk.

Primero, como norma general, no nombres a tus campos de tipo Foreignkey en el modelo de esta manera: producto_id, pedido_id. Cuando declaras un campo Foreignkey, por ejemplo "producto" django te va a generar una columna en tu BD con el nombre producto_id.

Con lo anterior, si quieres asignar un objeto entonces le pasas un objeto Producto directamente al campo "producto", si quieres pasarle un id en lugar de una instancia le pasas el id al campo "producto_id".

Como normal general, es nombrecampo_id para llenar la columna con un entero. Sin _id es para un objeto de la clase declarada en el campo Foreignkey.

Lo correcto seria:

```
class LineaPedido(models.Model):        
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.cantidad} unidades de {self.producto_id.nombre}'

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'lineapedidos'
        verbose_name = 'Línea Pedido'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Línea Pedidos'
        ordering=['id']
```

Ahora, para solucionar el problema, tienes dos opciones, la primera es indicarle que llene la columna _id de esta manera:

```
for key, value in carro.carro.items():
    lineas_pedido.append(LineaPedido(
        producto_id_id=key,
        cantidad=value["cantidad"],
        user=request.user,
        pedido_id_id=pedido
    ))
```

La alternativa es que obtengas el objeto y lo asignes de esta manera:

```
for key, value in carro.carro.items():
    lineas_pedido.append(LineaPedido(
        producto_id=Producto.objects.get(pk=key),
        cantidad=value["cantidad"],
        user=request.user,
        pedido_id=pedido
    ))
```

Comment: Hola, ahora tengo otro error que me a generado con tu solución en las dos me salen esto **TypeError: _str_ returned non-string (type int)** te adjunto una imagen arriba para que veas mejor el error

Comment: Te actualizo, fue mi error, no vi que ya creabas el objeto pedido antes, la parte de pedido_id si queda como pedido_id=pedido, te actualizo mi respuesta.

Comment: Funciono como dijiste muchas gracias, ya la marque como correcta pero como soy nuevo en stackoverfolw no sale nada. Ahora en el admin de djngo no me deja eliminar o modificar el pedido me sale el mismo error que el de arriba en la imagen pero en vez de poner **pedido Error in formatting...** pone **Obj Error in formatting: TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type int)** y perdona por las molestias es que soy nuevo en esto